# Windows Component Services console (dcomcnfg) hangs

Tags: windows, dcom, mmc

After run the "Component Services" console in any way and go to the Computers section, it hangs. Only the forced termination of the process helps.

At the same time there is some activity

[image: at the same time there is some activity].

Long wait does not help.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand how to identify the cause of the problem. To resolve this, do the following:

1. sfc /scannow
2. installing updates
3. reboot

after that, the console started working again.